How to make type inference work on a piece of code?
I have this (simplified) piece of code:
export abstract class Scheduler<TPayload> {}

export interface EventKey<T> extends Symbol {}

export type SystemSpecification<TPayload> = (
  args: {
    /** The value provided by current scheduler tick */
    payload: TPayload;
  },
) => void;

export function defineSystem<TPayload>(
  system: SystemSpecification<TPayload>,
  scheduler: new () => Scheduler<TPayload>
) {
  // ...
}

const on = <TPayload>(eventKey: EventKey<TPayload>) =>
  class extends Scheduler<TPayload> {
    // ...
  };

const clickEvent = Symbol('clickEvent') as EventKey<{ foo: 20 }>;

defineSystem(
  ({ payload }) => console.log(payload.foo),
  on(clickEvent)
);

I am expecting payload value to be infered from clickEvent type : {foo: number}, but instead, I have an error: 'payload' is of type unknown

Am I doing something wrong? Is it actually possible to infer payload from clickEvent type?
Playground

Here is how you can fix it.
Define constructor type SchedulerCtor and make sure you use it as type for scheduler: argument in defineSystem and as return type for on.
Also have a look at trailing comma — <TPayload,>


export abstract class Scheduler<TPayload> {}

export interface EventKey<T> extends Symbol {}

export type SystemSpecification<TPayload> = (
  args: {
    /** The value provided by current scheduler tick */
    payload: TPayload;
  },
) => void;

type SchedulerCtor<TPayload> = new () => Scheduler<TPayload>

export function defineSystem<TPayload>(
  system: SystemSpecification<TPayload>,
  scheduler: SchedulerCtor<TPayload>
) {
  // ...
}

const on = <TPayload,>(eventKey: EventKey<TPayload>): SchedulerCtor<TPayload> => {
  return class extends Scheduler<TPayload> {
    // ...
  };
};

const clickEvent = Symbol('clickEvent') as EventKey<{ foo: number }>;

defineSystem(
  ({ payload }) => console.log(payload.foo),
  on(clickEvent)
);



Trailing comma in the generic is not necessary if you set jsx to none in the tsconfig.

Yeah, this is just to make TS happier on a broader subset of environments

brilliant, thank you. As far as I understand the fix, type flow cannot be nested then unwrapped. Something like that ?
